# Use TortoiseSVN to manage linux files through ssh

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

My situation is the only method of accessing/modifying files on the linux machine is through WinSCP, and therefore have no way to use any SVN Clients for linux.

My company does not wish to use any command line SVN commands and therefore use TortoiseSVN for windows.

I was wondering if its possible to use TortoiseSVN from my windows machine to commit changes, do updates, etc on my linux machine through using ssh. My linux machine is not the svn server(nor is my windows machine), it needs to commit to the svn server.

If it helps, the Linux distribution I am using is SUSE

Any suggestions would be great with as much detail as possible as I am not an expert in this field.

Thanks,
TOWP

Edit (Attempt to make question clearer):

I am on my windows machine.

I have made changes to files sitting on a linux machine through WinSCP

I want to commit through changes on the linux machine using TortoiseSVN on my windows 
machine.

Not sure if its possible. I was also hoping to not need svn installed on the linux machine as I would be doing things through TortoiseSVN on my windows machine, but that would just be a bonus if that result could be accomplished.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. It's not clear what your looking for.

Comment: [Here](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) is some info on a TortoiseSVN SSH add-on that might enable you to connect to your repo that way.

Comment: Thanks Darth, however isn't that to setup an svn server? I may be wrong, but isn't that where it would be trying to commit to rather than  committing from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're going about this backwards.  I'd guess that the linux machine is some sort of runtime environment for your code and you're making changes to it and then want to apply them to version control.

I suspect what you really should be doing is checking the files out into a working copy on Windows, modifying them and then using winscp to apply them to the Linux box.

Alternatively, you could have [SVNPubSub setup on your SVN server and use svnwcsub to update a working copy](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/server-side/svnpubsub/) on the Linux box (but since you say you only have WinSCP access, that doesn't seem to be possible).

Another possible solution would be to share the working copy on the Linux machine to the Windows Machine (NFS, SMB, etc).  There are performance issues with doing so and you probably can't do that with just WinSCP.  There is a possibility of [mounting SFTP systems as a file system](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/), but I doubt that will work very well (if at all) since locking will be required.

You'll probably get a lot better answer if you're more specific about what you're trying to do.  You're still being rather vague.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I had all my thinking backwards. I am going to ask my boss today to understand the true purpose of the Linux machine, as we may be able to set something up to simply checkout the code nightly to the server.
Sorry again about the vagueness, its difficult being specific when you have no idea what is important as you are new to the field.